# Syntax for Table with a pure function

Tags: list-manipulation, pure-function

I have:

```
g = #1^2 + a #2^3 / #1 &
```

Now I wish to make a `Table` evaluating this from `1` to `10`

```
Table[ g, { #, 1, 10}]
```

fails.

What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe [`Array`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Array.html) is more suitable than `Table` for this task:

```
g = #1^2 + a #2^3/#1 &;
Array[g, {10, 10}]
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use [`Slot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Slot.html) (`#`) as an iterator. You have to apply an argument:

```
g = #1^2 + a #2^3/#1 &;
Table[g[i, i], {i, 1, 10}]
```

Comment: Thanks to all for the helpful answers

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to iterate on the first argument from 1 to 10 to get a list of 10 functions, you can use

```
Table[With[{i = i}, g[i, #] &], {i, 1, 10}]
(* {g[1, #1] &, g[2, #1] &, g[3, #1] &, g[4, #1] &, g[5, #1] &, 
    g[6, #1] &, g[7, #1] &, g[8, #1] &, g[9, #1] &, g[10, #1] &} *)
```

If you want to iterate both arguments from 1 to 10 (on the diagonal), you can use `Table` as in halirutan's answer, or `Array`

```
Array[g[#, #] &, {10}]
(* {15, 60, 135, 240, 375, 540, 735, 960, 1215, 1500} *)
```

For iterating each of the two arguments separately you can use `Array[g, {10, 10}]`  as in Karsten 7.'s answer, or

```
Table[g[i, j], {i, 10}, {j, 10}]
Table[g[i, j], {i, 10}, {j, 10}] ==Array[g, {10, 10}]
(* True *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Map is another concise alternative:

```
g = #1^2 + a #2^3/#1 &;
g[#, #] & /@ Range[10]
```